# AWS service-role unauthorized, until opened in the console and saved

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to set up a codeBuild project through the nodejs AWS-SDK. I'm able to create a new IAM role with policies attached, but when I use it in the `.createProject()` it gives me an error:

`CodeBuild is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on arn:aws:iam::[account]:role/service-role/[role-name]`

The weird thing is that, when I open the trusted relationships JSON of the role and save it (without any changes) it suddenly works.

the AssumeRole JSON file:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using a federated user. I don't know if that makes a difference (the process of requesting a regular account takes a few days, so I haven't tried that yet).

I tried to copy the before and after save to see what was going on, but when I store it in a file it has the exact same bytes. I'm really confused, I've been trying to fix this for almost half a day now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. Apparently, when you create a role and immediately start using it you'll get a "not authorized" error. But you also get this when the role doesn't even exist.

I added a manual wait of 10 seconds, not it works.

The SDK has a function for this called "waitfor", which can be used on roles and policies.